# how to sort an intList every 5 elements

Tags: java

im inserting thousand of numbers from a txt file into a list and i want to sort them every 5 numbers. Is this possible and if yes,how this can be done?

```
     public static void readFromFile(){
     List<Integer> putInList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     int jNum;
     TextIO.readFile("jokerNums.txt");//read from a spesific file.

     try{
         do{
             jNum = TextIO.getInt();
             putInList.add(jNum);

         } while(!TextIO.eof());//  Test whether the next character in 
         //the current input source is an end-of-file 
     } 

     catch(IllegalArgumentException e){

     } 
     TextIO.put(putInList);
 }
```

I have tried the for loop inside the do { }while loop but its  infinite.
Just to mention the numbers i insert are 9785.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not using a sorted collection like a `TreeSet`?

Comment: What do you mean "sort them every 5 numbers"? Can you give an example? Are you trying to get a fully sorted list of all the numbers in your file?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the entire array, every 5 numbers, or are you trying to sort every 5 numbers? i.e `[2,3,1,5,6, 4]` would sort when 6 was entered and become `[1,2,3,5,6, 4]`?

Comment: `sort them every 5 numbers` what does that mean? add an example of input with expected output.

Comment: if the numbers inserted are

Comment: if the numbers inserted are 40, 21, 44, 26, 36,      39, 16, 7, 19, 20,        18, 16, 17, 38, 5    i want to sort them like    21, 26, 36, 40, 44     7, 16, 19, 20, 39    5, 16 17, 18, 38  and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; !TextIO.eof(); i++){
      int value = TextIO.getInt();
      int targetIndex = (i/5)*5;
      for (; targetIndex < putInList.size(); targetIndex++)
      {
          if(putInList.get(targetIndex)>value)
          {
            break;
          }
      }
      putInList.add(targetIndex,value);

    }
```

Comment: <b>hunter<b> i have no words to thank you. Problem solved.